# Finetuning LLaMA for token classification errors

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, llama

For Roberta, I implemented a version of token classification that outputs the one hot encodings. You can find that [here](https://github.com/coen22/Comparison-QoC/blob/main/code/RobertaForMultiTokenClassification.py).
However, it doesn't work with LLaMA because of optimisations done elsewhere in the code.

This works

```
class RobertaForMultiLabelTokenClassification(RobertaPreTrainedModel):
    _keys_to_ignore_on_load_unexpected = [r"pooler"]
    _keys_to_ignore_on_load_missing = [r"position_ids"]

    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.num_labels = config.num_labels

        self.roberta = RobertaModel(config, add_pooling_layer=False)
        classifier_dropout = (
            config.classifier_dropout if config.classifier_dropout is not None else config.hidden_dropout_prob
        )
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(classifier_dropout)
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, config.num_labels)

        # Initialize weights and apply final processing
        self.post_init()

    def forward(
        self,
        input_ids: Optional[torch.LongTensor] = None,
        attention_mask: Optional[torch.FloatTensor] = None,
        token_type_ids: Optional[torch.LongTensor] = None,
        position_ids: Optional[torch.LongTensor] = None,
        head_mask: Optional[torch.FloatTensor] = None,
        inputs_embeds: Optional[torch.FloatTensor] = None,
        labels: Optional[torch.LongTensor] = None,
        output_attentions: Optional[bool] = None,
        output_hidden_states: Optional[bool] = None,
        return_dict: Optional[bool] = None,
    ) -> Union[Tuple[torch.Tensor], TokenClassifierOutput]:
        r"""
        labels (`torch.LongTensor` of shape `(batch_size, sequence_length)`, *optional*):
            Labels for computing the token classification loss. Indices should be in `[0, ..., config.num_labels - 1]`.
        """
        return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return_dict

        outputs = self.roberta(
            input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            token_type_ids=token_type_ids,
            position_ids=position_ids,
            head_mask=head_mask,
            inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,
            output_attentions=output_attentions,
            output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
            return_dict=return_dict,
        )

        sequence_output = outputs[0]

        sequence_output = self.dropout(sequence_output)
        logits = self.classifier(sequence_output)

        loss = None
        if labels is not None:
            loss_fct = BCEWithLogitsLoss()
            target: torch.LongTensor = labels.view(logits.size())
            loss = loss_fct(logits, target.float())

        logits = torch.sigmoid(logits)

        if not return_dict:
            output = (logits,) + outputs[2:]
            return ((loss,) + output) if loss is not None else output

        return TokenClassifierOutput(
            loss=loss,
            logits=logits,
            hidden_states=outputs.hidden_states,
            attentions=outputs.attentions,
        )
```

But this doesn't

```
class LlamaForTokenClassification(LlamaPreTrainedModel):
    _keys_to_ignore_on_load_unexpected = [r"pooler"]
    _keys_to_ignore_on_load_missing = [r"position_ids"]

    classifier_dropout = 0.1

    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.num_labels = config.num_labels
        self.llama = LlamaModel(config)

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(self.classifier_dropout)
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, config.num_labels)

        self.post_init()

    def forward(
            self,
            input_ids: torch.LongTensor = None,
            attention_mask: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None,
            position_ids: Optional[torch.LongTensor] = None,
            past_key_values: Optional[List[torch.FloatTensor]] = None,
            inputs_embeds: Optional[torch.FloatTensor] = None,
            labels: Optional[torch.LongTensor] = None,
            use_cache: Optional[bool] = None,
            output_attentions: Optional[bool] = None,
            output_hidden_states: Optional[bool] = None,
            return_dict: Optional[bool] = None,
    ) -> Union[Tuple[torch.Tensor], TokenClassifierOutput]:
        return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return_dict

        outputs = self.llama(
            input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            position_ids=position_ids,
            past_key_values=past_key_values,
            inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,
            use_cache=use_cache,
            output_attentions=output_attentions,
            output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
            return_dict=return_dict,
        )

        sequence_output = outputs[0]

        sequence_output = self.dropout(sequence_output)
        logits = self.classifier(sequence_output)

        loss = None
        if labels is not None:
            loss_fct = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
            target: torch.LongTensor = labels.view(logits.size())
            loss = loss_fct(logits, target.float())

        logits = torch.sigmoid(logits)

        if not return_dict:
            output = (logits,) + outputs[2:]
            return ((loss,) + output) if loss is not None else output

        return TokenClassifierOutput(
            loss=loss,
            logits=logits,
            hidden_states=outputs.hidden_states,
            attentions=outputs.attentions,
        )
```

When I run it using the default Trainer, I get an error about CUDA. I'm running a 3090 and finetuning for CasualLM works fine.

```
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1146: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [52,0,0], thread: [30,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
  File "/mnt/e/Comparison-QoC/code/LlamaForTokenClassification.py", line 152, in forward
    outputs = self.llama(
  File "/home/coen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/coen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward
    output = old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/coen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py", line 708, in forward
    layer_outputs = decoder_layer(
  File "/home/coen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/coen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward
    output = old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/coen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py", line 424, in forward
    hidden_states, self_attn_weights, present_key_value = self.self_attn(
  File "/home/coen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/coen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward
    output = old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/coen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py", line 321, in forward
    query_states = self.q_proj(hidden_states)
  File "/home/coen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/coen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward
    output = old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/coen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/nn/modules.py", line 248, in forward
    out = bnb.matmul_4bit(x, self.weight.t(), bias=bias, quant_state=self.weight.quant_state)
  File "/home/coen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/autograd/_functions.py", line 579, in matmul_4bit
    return MatMul4Bit.apply(A, B, out, bias, quant_state)
  File "/home/coen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/function.py", line 506, in apply
    return super().apply(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "/home/coen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/autograd/_functions.py", line 516, in forward
    output = torch.nn.functional.linear(A, F.dequantize_4bit(B, state).to(A.dtype).t(), bias)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED when calling `cublasCreate(handle)`
```

The issue shows a mismatch in size, but I don't see where the issue occurs.

Using the SFTTrainer, I get a NotImplemented exception.

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem:

```
class ClassificationHead(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config, num_labels):
        super().__init__()

        self.dense = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, config.hidden_size)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.1)
        self.out_proj = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, num_labels)

    def forward(self, features, **kwargs):
        # print(features.dtype, features)  # Check the dtype of features
        # print(self.dense.weight.dtype)  # Check the dtype of the weight matrix in self.dense
        # print(self.dense.bias.dtype)  # Check the dtype of the bias vector in self.dense

        features = features.float()  # Convert features to torch.float32
        x = self.dense(features)
        x = torch.tanh(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.out_proj(x)
        return x


class AutoModelForMultiTokenClassification(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pretrained_model_name, num_labels, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_labels = num_labels

        # Load pretrained model
        self.pretrained_model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(
            pretrained_model_name,
            load_in_8bit=True,
            torch_dtype=torch.float16,
        )

        # Add classification head
        self.classification_head = ClassificationHead(self.pretrained_model.config, num_labels)

        # Freeze the weights of pretrained_model
        for param in self.pretrained_model.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False

    def forward(
            self,
            input_ids=None,
            attention_mask=None,
            labels=None,  # Add labels argument
            return_dict: Optional[bool] = None,
            **kwargs,
    ):
        base_model_output = self.pretrained_model(
            input_ids=input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            output_hidden_states=True,
            **kwargs,
        )

        last_hidden_state = base_model_output[0]
        token_logits = self.classification_head(last_hidden_state.to(torch.float16))

        loss = None
        if labels is not None:
            labels = labels.to(token_logits.device)
            loss_fct = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
            target: torch.LongTensor = labels.view(token_logits.size())
            loss = loss_fct(token_logits, target.float())

        if not return_dict:
            output = (token_logits,) + base_model_output[2:]
            return ((loss,) + (token_logits,)) if loss is not None else output

        return TokenClassifierOutput(
            loss=loss,
            logits=token_logits,
            hidden_states=base_model_output.hidden_states,
            attentions=base_model_output.attentions,
        )
```

For my problem I also adjusted the DataCollatorForTokenClassification:

```
from typing import Union, Optional

from transformers import PreTrainedTokenizerBase
from transformers.data.data_collator import DataCollatorMixin
from transformers.utils import PaddingStrategy
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class DataCollatorForTokenClassification(DataCollatorMixin):
    """
    Data collator that will dynamically pad the inputs received, as well as the labels.

    Args:
        tokenizer ([`PreTrainedTokenizer`] or [`PreTrainedTokenizerFast`]):
            The tokenizer used for encoding the data.
        padding (`bool`, `str` or [`~utils.PaddingStrategy`], *optional*, defaults to `True`):
            Select a strategy to pad the returned sequences (according to the model's padding side and padding index)
            among:

            - `True` or `'longest'` (default): Pad to the longest sequence in the batch (or no padding if only a single
              sequence is provided).
            - `'max_length'`: Pad to a maximum length specified with the argument `max_length` or to the maximum
              acceptable input length for the model if that argument is not provided.
            - `False` or `'do_not_pad'`: No padding (i.e., can output a batch with sequences of different lengths).
        max_length (`int`, *optional*):
            Maximum length of the returned list and optionally padding length (see above).
        pad_to_multiple_of (`int`, *optional*):
            If set will pad the sequence to a multiple of the provided value.

            This is especially useful to enable the use of Tensor Cores on NVIDIA hardware with compute capability >=
            7.5 (Volta).
        label_pad_token_id (`int`, *optional*, defaults to -100):
            The id to use when padding the labels (-100 will be automatically ignore by PyTorch loss functions).
        return_tensors (`str`, *optional*, defaults to `"pt"`):
            The type of Tensor to return. Allowable values are "np", "pt" and "tf".
    """

    tokenizer: PreTrainedTokenizerBase
    padding: Union[bool, str, PaddingStrategy] = 'max_length'
    max_length: Optional[int] = None
    pad_to_multiple_of: Optional[int] = None
    label_pad_token_id: int = -100
    num_labels: int = 4
    return_tensors: str = "pt"

    def torch_call(self, features):
        import torch

        label_name = "label" if "label" in features[0].keys() else "labels"
        labels = [feature[label_name] for feature in features] if label_name in features[0].keys() else None

        no_labels_features = [{k: v for k, v in feature.items() if k != label_name} for feature in features]

        batch = self.tokenizer.pad(
            no_labels_features,
            padding=self.padding,
            max_length=self.max_length,
            pad_to_multiple_of=self.pad_to_multiple_of,
            return_tensors="pt",
        )

        if labels is None:
            return batch

        sequence_length = batch["input_ids"].shape[1]
        padding_side = self.tokenizer.padding_side

        def to_list(tensor_or_iterable):
            if isinstance(tensor_or_iterable, torch.Tensor):
                return tensor_or_iterable.tolist()
            return list(tensor_or_iterable)

        if padding_side == "right":
            batch[label_name] = [
                to_list(label) + [[self.label_pad_token_id] * self.num_labels] * (sequence_length - len(label)) for
                label in labels
            ]
        else:
            batch[label_name] = [
                [[self.label_pad_token_id] * self.num_labels] * (sequence_length - len(label)) + to_list(label) for
                label in labels
            ]

        # print(type(batch[label_name]), batch[label_name])

        batch[label_name] = torch.tensor(batch[label_name], dtype=torch.int64)
        return batch
```